# Notepad++ saving to a full hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, notepad++, data-loss-prevention

I do a lot of my web development in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) on a Windows XP machine.  The development happens on a remote server (Windows 2003) used for a variety of jobs, so it often fills up.

When the hard drive is full and I save a file, I do not receive any sort of error in Notepad++.  Everything appears to save normally from the application.  However, the text file save as an empty file, likely because there is no space to save the changes.

I usually catch the problem when I refresh my web browser and see a blank webpage.  Occasionally though, I close the file after a quick edit, and if the data was not saved, it is lost.

Is there a setting in Notepad++ to alert me if the file was not saved correctly?  Is this something that should be checked at the OS level?

Comment: The OS should tell the application (notepad) and it should tell you.

Comment: I would tell you to get a better editor but where would you put it.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with Notepad++.  I would either provide more storage space to the server, set the default location location to some other storage device, or find a better tool that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Have you considered saving the file locally and copying it to the server? You would then get a copy error to let you know it did not work.

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm trying to avoid adding steps to the save process.  Copying over the file afterwards would work, but I hope that's a last resort.

Comment: @richard I've gotten quite used to using Notepad++, and don't want to abandon it just yet if there's a way I can get an alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug within Notepad++, the bug [#2891 Zero file length when saving to a full drive](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/2891/), was reported in 2010 (or years ago from your question date).  It's been marked as open, though not assigned yet.  If the problem is irritating, perhaps consider [donating](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/donate/) to the [team](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contributors/), they may help you out.

Comment: That bug description looks like my problem exactly. I guess if it's a known bug and it's still open, then at this time, there is no solution.  Thanks for the info.